# Difference between 'Bulgarian Split Squat' and 'Split Squat'

Tags: squats, terminology

I have seen the terms Split Squat and Bulgarian Split Squat used as if they refer to different exercises (i.e. in the same program) but my web searches make it seem as though they are two names for the same exercise.

Both seem to be a squat done with one leg behind you on a bench.

Is there a distinction between Bulgarian Split Squats and Split Squats?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a slight distinction between the two.  And, it may depend on your training experience.  Older trainers tend to refer to the Bulgarian Split Squat as the one in which the rear leg is typically elevated on a bench while performing the squat.  However, the [split squat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1jukGZPnZI) is a somewhat different movement in that the rear foot remains planted on the floor.  A split squat is often done with dumbbells for variation.

So, in the end, the only difference is really the rear foot placement while performing the movement no matter what you call the exercise.

In summary: a Bulgarian Split Squat may imply that the rear foot is elevated on a bench while a Split Squat may imply that the rear foot is not elevated.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. In fact the proper name of the exercise is actually 
**Bulgarian Split Squat**

However in weightlifting culture, perhaps whatever you read was referring to the 
**Bulgarian Squat Method**

The Bulgarian squat method was the method used by Bulgarian weightlifters during the period that they dominated the Olympics in the C&J and snatch.The method consisted of squatting to a daily maximum several times a day practically every day of the week, among other Olympic lifts.

Comment: Does the bulgarian squat method have anything to do with the bulgarian split squat?